# How to add "<" in Site Column Calculated (Sharepoint Online Add-in)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio

I'm development a sharepoint add-in in sharepoint online and visual studio 2017. I was used calculated fields with conditions like ">", but when I put "<" inside, I get a IDE error?

Anyone know how to escape it ?

> ```
> <Formula>=IF([JanuaryGoal] < 0, "zero", "ok") </Formula>
>
>   <FieldRefs>
>     <FieldRef Name="JanuaryGoal"/>
>   </FieldRefs>
> ```

[image: Error "<" in site column calculated field formula]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use escape characters.... below is what you need.

```
<Formula>=IF([JanuaryGoal] &lt; 0, "zero", "ok") </Formula>

  <FieldRefs>
    <FieldRef Name="JanuaryGoal"/>
  </FieldRefs>
```

Ref for other special characters - https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/xml-escaped-chars.html